# Why do so many formula use Euler's number "e"?

Tags: exponential-function

Why do so many formula use Euler's number?
What's the role of the "e" about in many formula?

I know that it's 2.7xxxx value and something good for compound interest.
Please tell me how I think it as, when faced with in some formula.

$ex
\begin{eqnarray}\sigma(z) \equiv\frac{1}{1+e^{-z}}\tag{3}\end{eqnarray}$

Comment: $e=2.71828182845904523536028747135266\dots$ and it appears a lot because of calculus.

Comment: @A.Molendijk which is a very legitimate question.